# How to autoincrement values checkbox with jinja2 (Django) with reset

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I need to autoincrement value in my checkbox and reset value when I generated new massive of checkbox

```
forloop.count dont reset
```

```
{% for ans in Answ %}

    {% if ans.question_id_id == Questions.id %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ Questions.id }}" name="id">
       <div class="form-check" ><label><input type="checkbox" value="{{ ans.id }}" name="answer"> {{ ans.answer }} </label></div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class AnswerQuestionView (LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
login_url = '/login'
redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
model = Question
template_name = 'index.html'
context_object_name = 'Questions'
slug_field = 'pk'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AnswerQuestionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_group'] = self.request.user.groups.values_list()[0][1]
    context['Answ'] = QuestAnswer.objects.all()

    return context
```

Comment: Please share the related view.

Comment: add views.py @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the *many* reasons why you should *not* do filtering in the template. Another very important one is performance: as the number of answers will grow, eventually the template rendering will take *a lot* of time.

You can filter in the view with:

```
class AnswerQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    model = Question
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_group'] = self.request.user.groups.values_list()[0][1]
        context['answers'] = QuestAnswer.objects.filter(question_id=self.object)
        return context
```

You probably can even use the related name:

```
class AnswerQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    model = Question
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_group'] = self.request.user.groups.values_list()[0][1]
        context['answers'] = self.object.questionanswer_set.all()
        return context
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `question`, instead of <s>`question_id`</s>.